# Scored Labels dont match Scored Probabilities

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a predictive web service. The scored labels field don't match the highest value for the specific scored probabilities columns. Is it more reliable to search through the different columns and pick the highest?

Like, I get a result that has a bunch of 
"Scored Probabilities for Class" \"\"": 0.6,
"Scored Probabilities for Class" \"\"": 3.09

But the scored labels show the one with 0.6, how is that possible?

Comment: Scored Probabilities for Class is 3.09 > 1. I didn't get this part.

Comment: Me neither to be honest, there could be a problem with the model where it ignores those because they all should be <1